# I know this sentence is wrong but

Tags: adverbs

I'm trying to explain to the person who wrote it, and to myself, why it is wrong.

> Dan plays the drums as vindictively as though they’d personally insulted him.

The "as adverbially as though" is wrong. I've edited it to:

> Dan plays the drums vindictively, as though they’d personally insulted him.

but I want to know why I had to.

Comment: Nowadays, I think we would use *as vindictively as if* rather than *as vindictively as though*. However, *as vindictively as though* used to be much more common. I can't see why the first should be more grammatical than the second. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+quickly+as+if%2C+as+quickly+as+though&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20quickly%20as%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20quickly%20as%20though%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Your edit changes the implication: I wouldn't think the minor improvement in tone is worth it, and certainly wouldn't say the original is 'wrong'.

Comment: You're mixing up two constructions: the equative _as...as..._ construction, and the hypothetical metaphor tag _as though `S`_. They both use _as_'s, but you can't overlap them.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue. That others here don't see this problem is worrying me though.

Comment: @Peter Shor: It's an interesting analysis but I think it's better suited to study how idiomatic expressions have changed over time.  We can't conclude that a phrase is grammatically correct today based only on the fact that it was published a few times during the course of human history (case in point: try searching for "you're computer" and you'll see that its usage has been rising steadily since the mid 80s!).  As @John Lawler points out, the first usage is not correct English as it mixes two constructions, both of which happen to use `as`.

Comment: @Dipak: it's not just "published a few times during the course of human history". It's been used several times by famous authors. Rudyard Kipling: *"I remember all this as clearly as though a photograph were in my hand."* Bram Stoker: *"... the light of it shone from seven stars, each of seven points, as clearly as though the stars were in reality there imprisoned."* If Kipling and Stoker use a construction, it's not inarguably wrong.

Comment: Those sentences by Kipling and Stoker actually sound fine to me (in contrast to the example in the OP) but I'm unable to articulate why.  Good point, though.  I'll defer to someone who's more familiar with parts of speech but I suspect the issue might be stylistic. (Btw, I agree with your original suggestion that, in this day and age, "as if" is more idiomatic than either of the two examples in the original post.)

Comment: I actually think Kipling and Stoker sound wrong too. The if/though is a minor secondary issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you go by usage, it isn't wrong. Several famous writers have used this construction both with *"as **adverb** as if"* and *"as **adverb** as though"*. Some of these I found with Google book search, and others through citations in the OED.

> 1602 William Shakespeare: *Merry Wives of Windsor*;  I'faith, Ile eate nothing: I thanke you as much as though I did.  (OED)
>
> 1749 Henry Fielding: *Tom Jones*;  He..would have had us consider ourselves as highly, as if we had been the richest Heiresses. (OED)
>
> 1871 Mark Twain: *About Barbers*; I said meekly that I was in a hurry, and it affected him as strongly as if he had never heard it.
>
> 1888 Rudyard Kipling: *Plain Tales from the Hills*; I remember all this as clearly as though a photograph were in my hand.
>
> 1903 Bram Stoker: *The Jewel of Seven Stars*; ...  the light of it shone from seven stars, each of seven points, as clearly as though the stars were in reality there imprisoned.
>
> 1906 H.G. Wells: *In the Days of the Comet*; It is a fact that for the best part of the morning of the Change I forgot Nettie and Verrall as completely as though they were no more than characters in some novel ...
>
> 1915 John Buchan: *Thirty-nine Steps*;  You can lie as snug here as if you were in a moss-hole. (OED)
>
> 1922 P.G. Wodehouse: *The Clicking of Cuthbert*;  I was fond of Mortimer Sturgis, and I could see trouble ahead for him as plainly as though I had been a palmist reading his hand at two guineas a visit.
>
> 1938 Graham Greene: *Brighton Rock*; She saw him at once; his attention rang in her brain as quickly as if he had dialled her.
>
> 2006 Margaret Drabble: *The Sea Lady*; That section of his life is as though it had never been: it has been excised as neatly as though the protective Mrs Hornby herself had dictated the terms.

Also, the *OED* says that *"as if"* and *"as though"* both mean *"as the case would be if"*. 
Substituting this in the sentence yields:

> Dan plays the drums as vindictively as the case would be if they'd personally insulted him.

I don't see anything wrong with the expanded version.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because there are two distinct constructions being combined into one phrase. Isolate the first part of the sentence:

"Dan plays the drums as vindictively as..."

You'd use this "as ... as" construction if you wanted to set up a specific kind of simile (ex. "Dan plays the drums as vindictively as a child ignored by his parents."). "Dan plays the drums" is the tenor, or the subject, of the simile. The tenor needs a vehicle, or object, to be compared to.

"... as though they'd personally insulted him" isn't an object Dan's playing is being compared to. "As though" is a subordinating conjunction. The sentence would work as "Dan plays the drums as though they'd personally insulted him." because "as though" is joining the clause "they'd personally insulted him" with "Dan plays the drums." The result is a comparison to a hypothetical situation.

Comment: What *exactly* is the grammatical problem with it? I agree it sounds funny because we don't often see *"as though"* used in this way, but why is it actually incorrect?

Comment: @Peter Shore. Replace "though" with "if", the problem remains. The second "as" is serving two masters, two separate constructions that overlap. One construction is in square parentheses, the other in curved ones. "The stars shone [as brightly (as] if) they were with us."

Comment: The OED defines *"as if"* by *"as the case would be if"*. So *"Dan plays the drums as vindictively as the case would be if they'd personally insulted him"*. I don't see anything wrong with the expanded version. And they have the 1603 citation *"arrowes fell as thicke..as if it had been a perpetuall..shoure of haile"*, which is an early example of this construction.

Comment: The problem, as analysed above by Pixie and John Lawler, remains in your expansion. And I accept the construction has been used in multiple authoritative places. It is the expectation of what should follow the second "as" (some object) with what actually follows: the "though/if" that reaches back and grabs the immediately preceding "as" for its own purposes, a hypothetical simile or what have you.